# two textviews in listview with arrayadapter and arraylist

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

i m displaying a listview with two textviews .the first textview is used for displaying the name of the location and the second one is for displaying address. i anm retrieving values from database and adding those values in an arraylist. i used a custom arrayadapter class named myadapter inflated the two textviews there but when i set the textviewresourse id of one of the textview i get both the values in a single textview. i want them in sepetate textviews. here is my code in display activity in which i am adding values in an arraylist

```
c.move(3);
            //  x1=c.getColumnIndex("_id");
            //    y1=c.getColumnIndex("latitude");
            //    z1=c.getColumnIndex("longiitude");
            //    w1=c.getColumnIndex("address");
              x = c.getColumnName(0);
              y = c.getColumnName(1);
              z = c.getColumnName(2);
              w = c.getColumnName(3);
              n=c.getColumnName(4);

     // tv_id.setText(x.toString().toUpperCase());
            //tv_lat.setText(y.toString().toUpperCase());
            //tv_lon.setText(z.toString().toUpperCase());
            // tv_add.setText(w.toString().toUpperCase());
            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
        do  
        {
                 a = c.getInt(0);
                 b1 = c.getDouble(1);
                 c1 = c.getDouble(2);
                 e = c.getString(3);            
                 f=c.getString(4);

                 results.add(e+"\n"+f);

            }  
            while (c.moveToNext()); }

            Myadapter adapter=new Myadapter(this, R.layout.row,R.id.text2, results);


            lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            //lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            lv.setCacheColorHint(Color.WHITE);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

here R.id.text2 is id of the second textview.
here is my code in myadapter class

```
public Myadapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> results) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, results);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
        this.results=results;

    }

    private List<String> results;
Context context;




    private static final String LayoutInflater = null;

@Override
     public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
          String name=results.get(position);
          String address=results.get(position);
            if (convertView == null) {
                 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            TextView tv11 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text11);
            tv11.setText(name);

            TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            text2.setText(address);
    pls help me. here is the row.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text11"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textColor="#000000"
         />


          <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="10sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
         />

          <Button android:text="Delete" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" 
          ></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

pls help me i want name to appear in first textview and address in the second. pls help me. thanks and regards

Comment: Are you able to get the desired layout of a row by viewing it in graphical layout in eclipse using static text?

Comment: i am getting the layout in graphical layout. pls tell me how to add arraylist items in seperate textviews. i am getting both the values in single textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your layout

```
    android:id="@+id/text2"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

in your second text view. you have aligned both textviews to left. change the alignment of the second textview as mentioned above. but still you will encounter overlapping if one of the text is huge.